# having trouble in tabbar in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, tabbar

i am new in android.
i am using android fragment tab .i follow the following tutorial.
http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/
but problem is that i have more than one activities in on tab now what am missing.
i mean i have Tab1 : activity A-->activity B--> activity c -->
any body can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please follow the link
Hope it will solve yours problem.

https://github.com/rameshkec85/BottomTabsFragmentTabHost

https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip[image]